# Azure Ad Authorization is not working in .net 7 mvc, roleClaims count is empty

Tags: azure-active-directory, .net-6.0, azure-authentication

I have implemented Azure Ad Authentication in my .net7 mvc webapp, but failed(actually stuck) to add Azure role based authorization.
I have registered the app, created the roles, and assigned to my user in Azure portal also added the code in my webapp.

Program.cs file for authorization code.
[image: Program.cs : authorization code]

Appsettings.json

[image: appsetttings.json]

I have followed this [Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles) example and searched many articles but noting is working for me and still HttpContext.User.Claims count is zero in my controller's method. Can someone please help me or refer some tutorial for end to end implementation of Azure Ad authorization in .net 6 mvc webapp.
I will be grateful to that person. Need help!!!

Comment: What roles do you expect to see? Should they be mapped from Azure AD Security Groups?

Comment: Which example did you follow? This one: `5-WebApp-AuthZ\5-1-Roles`?

Comment: What does it mean exactly: "get 0 role count in my controller"? I have it working for me.

Comment: @VladDX Thanks for your time and comments but I got the solution it is just some miss configuration in Azure portal. I have missed to add group claims with directory roles, now roles are available in HttpContext.User object in my .net7 mvc app.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue with the help of a senior, and want to share the solution so might be helpful for someone. It is just a miss configuration in Azure portal.

[image]

The solution is go to **App Registration** choose your app, then select **Token Configuration** click on add group claim, select the checkbox **Direcory roles** and select these three properties **ID**, **Access**, and **SAML** with option **sAMAccountName**. Now the roles are available in HttpContext.User object.

[image]

Comment: Great that you figured it out. I believe there are 2-3 ways how to manage roles/groups in Azure AD for the web app. But if it works, it works.

Comment: @VladDX can you please tell me what are other ways to manage roles/groups or give some reference where I can know more about these, just for getting knowledge...

Comment: You can use "Security Groups", you can use "App Roles", you can use custom claims. The tutorial that you referred to uses App Roles. All the info is available by the link you shared. There are recordings and docs.